# ruby regex dotall without dotall /s flag

Tags: ruby, regex

Everyone.

I think I'm missing something in ruby regex.

It seems that I cannot use `%r/match code/s` because Ruby has only `/m`, wich is not allows me to search my match line ignoring new line symbols.

What I need for now:

```
line 1 : a b c
line 2 : a b
line 3 : c
line 4 : a
line 5 : b c
```

I need to find here three matches

```
1. a b c
2. a b (new line) c
3. a ( new line ) b c
```

This can be done by using /s flag, but /s flag is used for encoding in Ruby, and /m flag just gives me this one match with all text

```
a b c 
a b ( new line ) c
a ( new line ) b c
```

when I search expression like this `%r/a.*c/m`

I will appreciate for any information.

Comment: Your shift key isn't working well. You might want to look into getting it fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby is using `m` to enable the dotall mode, see [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html). So your expression is exactly doing what you want the `s` modifier for.

Your problem is a different one, your regex is matching too greedy. So you should change it to

```
%r/a.*?c/m
```

so the `.*?` will only match to the **next** "c" and not to the last.

Comment: Thank you, its working. But how can i use ? symbol for a word or a phrase ? like a b c *.?aa bb cc so that ? symbol was applied not only for "a" letter but for aa bb cc

Comment: @AutoCoder, In my solution the `?` does only modify the matching behaviour of the `*` quantifier. If you use the `?` after a character or a group, it is itself a quantifier, matching the preceding item 0 or 1 time. So, `a b c *.?(aa bb cc)?` would make that last part optional, but I am not sure if that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn off greediness of the star, so that it'll stop on first "c"

```
/(a.*?c)/m
```

See demo here: http://rubular.com/r/D8RptUOsjR