# regex: stop matching when end of line

Tags: regex, ruby-2.0

I want to scan a text composed of lines. When I recognize a keyword I am using a regex for this type of line.

My text has this form:

```
text<eol>
...
Function1 parameter1 value1, parameter2 value2, .... parameterN value N<eol>
...
text<eol>
```

In this case, when I recognize "Function1", I use this regex:

```
(?:(\w+)\s|\G(?<!^))[ ]*(\S+[ ]+\S+)\s*,?

$1 = the keyword Function1
$3 = parameterx valuex
```

I would like to stop the matching when the end of line is found.

```
while mytext =~ /.../ do
 case $3
  when 'parameter1 value1'
   ...
 end #case
 $'
end #while
```

My code is correct excepted when the matching is close to the end of line:my regex captures a part a the next line.

The question is: what can I add in my regex to stop when end of line ?
I suppose I must add $ somewhere ?

**Note:**
Sorry I copied the wrong regex ([] gave me an error with Ruby 2.0).
Note the space before the first star !

```
(?:(\w+)(\s+)|\G(?<!^)) *(\S+\s+\S+)\s*,?
```

Comment: see my note, [ ] gave me errors !

Comment: Oh, but can you still try putting a single space instead of `\s`?

Comment: Like this:   (?:(\w+)(  +)|\G(?<!^)) *(\S+  +\S+) *,?    No matches

Comment: Or like this: (?:(\w+)(\s+)|\G(?<!^)) *(\S+\s+\S+) *,? matches with 2 parameter-value, not with more

Comment: It's really better but I lost the keyword "Function1"

Comment: Oh, my bad. In so doing, I removed some capture groups. I put the first one back [here](http://regex101.com/r/zE2nW1). How does it work now?

Comment: The option "g" doesn't exist for Ruby

Comment: I think it's global by default. Hmm, I don't think you should need any flags here. So, I believe the regex should work in ruby without using the g flag. I'm not sure however whether `\G` works :s

Comment: How to you restart the tests with your tool ?

Comment: It updates automatically as you change the input/regex.

Comment: It's perfect with your tool. How to vote ?

Comment: Hmm, I could add an answer on which you can vote. I take it though that it still doesn't work on ruby? :(

Comment: The two answers (you and @alitaralmind) gave me matters of reflexion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, since you asked for it, here it is:

```
(?:(\w+) +|(?!^)\G) *(\S+ +[^\n, ]+) *,?
```

I changed all the `\s` into whitespaces and the last `\S` to `[^\n, ]` so that the comma after the value is not consumed during the matching.

I made some more minor changes regarding the capture groups and the way you were negating the `^` for the `\G` anchor.

It's working on PCRE flavoured regex like on [this demo site](http://regex101.com/r/zE2nW1) but like I said, I'm not entirely sure `\G` works on Ruby. Would be glad if someone could confirm this.

Comment: Thank You. Do you like to eat frogs ?

Comment: @Bertaud You're welcome! I haven't had the opportunity to taste frogs yet.

Comment: Still one question: is that correct to do that: while ... $' end ?

Comment: @Bertaud No, if you have `$`, it will only match functions with only one parameter/value pair.

Comment: $ followed by ' means next match ? Nevertheless the matching doesn't stop when \n is reached: the g option is missing for Ruby 2.00. Show my while in my question !

Comment: @Bertaud I'm not familiar with Ruby, that's my current problem here :( Have you tried using [`scan`](http://ideone.com/AHHcpr)?

Answer (score 1):

To stop matching at the end of lines, you should first make sure that the [`dotall` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13878142/2736496) is not active.

If the regular expression

```
(?:(\w+)\s|\G(?<!^))[ ]*(\S+[ ]+\S+)\s*,?
```

is working for you, then simply add start (`^`) and/or end-of-line (`$`) boundaries to it, such as:

```
^(?:(\w+)\s|\G(?<!^))[ ]*(\S+[ ]+\S+)\s*,?$
```

---

But it seems that your goal is to first find a line with a function-signature and capture the function name. So first you'll need to match the entire line with

```
^(\w+)\s+(?:(?:\w+\s+\w+)(?:, *)?)+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/BX9rr0SABXn3ogf2)

(The function name is in capture group one.)

Then, starting at the first non-whitespace character following the function name, iterate through each parameter with

```
\b(\w+)\s+(\w+)\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/16T5Z2yJ40yzGPLJ)

Comment: ^(?:(\w+)(\s+)|\G(?<!^)) *(\S+\s+\S+)\s*,?$ tells me No Matches

Comment: So it seems like you need an entirely different regex. If I'm understanding you, your goal is to capture the function name, and then iterate through all parameters. I've updated my answer assuming this is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately each line has not the same structure. Each line begins by a keyword but the following can be different ... The common point is that the function terminates at the end of line. I wrote <eol> which could confuse people. I meant \n

Comment: I see exactly one possible line-format in your question-post. Please consider providing more realistic examples next time, so we can give you better answers.

Comment: Read the first sentence of my question. I asked for one kind of line. Don't worry, I will analyse your proposition because very instructive for me. How did you write your graphs ? with debuggex ?

Comment: "I want to scan a text composed of lines. When I recognize a keyword I am using a regex for this type of line." I don't understand how that informs us of different line-formats. But thank you for the up-vote. Best of luck.

Comment: You are right. I wasn't precise ... for a swiss guy ;-)

Comment: why not ? As swiss french I like to eat frogs ... but you didn't answer to my question: how did you write your graphs ? Is it possible to draw a graph and generate a regex with ?

Comment: Debuggex does it for you. And as a Kermit super-fan I am required to take offense at your frog-comment.  ;)

Comment: You are in wrong: with garlic and butter it's delicious. The graphic is drawn from the regex, not the inverse !

Comment: Try RegexMagic. I don't use it. I use their RegexBuddy, which is for analyzing regexes, and is excellent. RegexMagic is for *constructing* regexes, and is perhaps what you are interested in.

Comment: Ruby's version of the DOTALL/singleline flag is called `multiline`, but that doesn't matter if there are no dots in the regex.  (`^` and `$` always match at line boundaries in Ruby, so no worries there.)

Comment: `multiline` was part of the original part of my answer, which turned out to not be satisfactory. I've separated the parts more clearly with a horizontal rule.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about regex specific to ruby. But I think, adding `[^<eol>]` should help exclude new lines. Try this simple change:

```
(?:(\w+)(\s+)|\G(?<!^)) *(\S+\s+\S+)\s*[^<eol>],?
```

Comment: for me <eol> means end of line. Shall I replace it by \n in your regex ?

Comment: Invalid conditional pattern.

Comment: Yes. Replace <eol> by \n.

Comment: Invalid conditional pattern.

Comment: This won't work anyway.  Forcing the regex to match a character that's not `\n` (or whatever) is not the same as preventing it from matching a `\n`.